# PHP: переменные пути в include

Tags: php, include

Получаю из БД массив $array, в котором хранятся значения:

```
sys_name
path
filename
```

Засовываю прогоняю через for, дабы сделать различные подключения файлов:

```
for($s=1; $s<=count($array)-1; $s++){
    if($module==$array[$s]['sys_name']) {
    include('./modules/'.$array[$s]['module_type'].'/'.$array[$s]['filename'].'.php');
}}
```

Но, ничего не происходит. Где ошибка?

Comment: $array покажите... и что за $module

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 15
    [active] => 0
    [ru_name] => некоторое имя
    [en_name] => some eng name
    [module_type] => news
    [sys_name] => news
    [link] => news
)Array
(
    [id] => 16
    [active] => 0
    [ru_name] => некоторое имя
    [en_name] => some eng name
    [module_type] => expos
    [sys_name] => expos
    [link] => expos
)

$module = получаю из адресной строки

Comment: ключ filename отсутствует

Comment: там filename = link  - использовал кусочки из немного разных версий своего кода

Comment: Не совсем понятно с чем вы сравниваете и почему через for?
$module = 'phpedit';
 $array[0]['sys_name'] = 'phpedit';
 $array[0]['filename'] = 'filename';
 $array[0]['module_type'] = 'type';
    if($module==$array[0]['sys_name']) {
    $include = './modules/'.$array[0]['module_type'].'/'.$array[0]['filename'].'.php';
 echo $include;
Нормально срабатывает. Лучше через foreach берите данные

Comment: И что за сравнение с $module? это даже не массив, а вы сравниваете элементы массива с этой переменной ._. Вы уточните что конкретно хотите сделать.

Comment: индексы массива начинаются с нуля, у вас же идет отсчет до единицы. А так, как сказали выше, массивы перебирать лучше с использованием `foreach`. Либо сразу выбирайте из БД данные по имени требуемого модуля.

Comment: По факту(как хочется что бы работало: получаю из адресной строки параметр module через $_GET. преобразовываю это в переменную $module. Получаю из sql массив, в котором содержаться: имена модуля, системной имя модуля, путь(папка в которой он лежит), файл к которому обращаться. Далее сравниваю $module с системными именем модуля, если совпадает - подгружаю файл include-ом. внутри инклуда соответственно часть пути и имя файла прописана в виде $переменных.  Так ведь можно, да?

Comment: о, заработало! убрал нафиг for, изменил на while. Сейчас выкину, как работает, может кому будет нужно

Comment: $getsections=$conn->query('SELECT * FROM sections WHERE active=1'); 
 while($section=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getsections)){
 if($module==$section['sys_name']) {
 include('./modules/'.$section['module_type'].'/'.$section['link'].'.php');
} }

Comment: Только для чего это?:) Можно через composer и autoload запускать те файлы, что вызываются в данный момент.

Comment: эм, а можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

1. Репы не хватает чтобы писать прямо под Вашим вопросом.
2. Вы на выходе получаете ассоциативный массив, поэтому цикл foreach сработал. В цикле for Вы обращались к массиву по несуществующим ключам, поэтому ничего не работало.
3. noxom, не всегда и не везде используется composer, он не является стандартом de facto.